# Advance mysql query question for contact app

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I'm making a contact app (with CodeIgniter and jQuery Mobile) and I'm at the point where I'm trying to insert list dividers for each grouping of names.

Example:

```
A
Adam Smith
Alex Smith

B
Beth Smith
Billy Smith
```

So far I can get names alphabetically from mysql db: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19118763/screenshots/before.png

THE CODE

```
<?php
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `CONTACTS` ORDER BY `CONTACTS`.`FIRST` ASC LIMIT 0, 100"); 
foreach($query->result() as $row):  
?>

<li><a href="contacts/details/<?=$row->ID?>/index.php" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown"><?=$row->FIRST?> <?=$row->LAST?></a></li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But, once I add the following code to get the first letter of each name, I get the following result: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19118763/screenshots/after.png

SAME CODE AS ABOVE execept added this in the foreach

```
<li data-role='list-divider'><?php echo substr("$row->FIRST",0,1); ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the code you linked with this:

```
<?php
$prevletter = null;
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `CONTACTS` ORDER BY `CONTACTS`.`FIRST` ASC LIMIT 0, 100"); foreach($query->result() as $row):  
$letter = substr($row->FIRST, 0, 1);
if ($letter != $prevletter):
$prevletter = $letter;
?>
<li data-role='list-divider'><?=$letter?></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<li><a href="contacts/details/<?=$row->ID?>/index.php" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown"><?=$row->FIRST?> <?=$row->LAST?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That should do what you need.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you very much.

BOOM: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19118763/Screenshots/irvu.png

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to check if the 'first letter" has already been output previously, and only output a letter when it changes:

```
$previous_letter = null; // prime things with an "impossible" letter.

while(...) {
   if ($previous_letter != substr($row->FIRST, 0, 1)) {
       ... ouptut new letter ...
       $previous_letter = new letter...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because for every row you come across you're echoing the first letter. You only want to echo the first letter if it's different than the last first letter.

pseudo code:

```
$prev = null
foreach (rows as row){
    $curr = substr(row->first, 0, 1)
    if ($prev != $curr){
        echo list-divider
        $prev = $curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea, I realized why the code was doing what it was doing, just didn't know how to make it do what I wanted :P